Node Services and Enum Sharing
I will get to the question in a minute....
We have 2 in house services that either have an API contract between the 2 that involves an enum or the enum value is stored in a shared database.
I don't consider copying this enum class between the 2 services' source a good idea, but creating a shared library has draw backs as well.
Now let the number of services grow that need to share this enum and making a change to it does require the update and redeployment of all services involved.
Now let the number of enums that are shared between the services grow and the question comes, should I share all the enums in a large library? This would make less libraries but cause more sharing of the library and more frequent changes to the library and cause more deployments.
Smaller libraries that are more focused would help that situation, but makes more libraries to maintain.
Finally my question...
What have people found to be the best way to share items like enums between contractually bound services that utilize the same data that is represented by the said enum?

More of a question for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com
